# OnCollisionStay Vs OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I've been using Unity for a while and for the life of me I can still not tell the difference between OnCollisionStay and OnCollisionEnter. I'm assuming that OncollisionEnter is called when a rigidbody (like a ball) makes contact with another rigidbody/collider such as a wall. But when I look at the example for OnCollisionStay, I get completely confused. Even if its called once per frame, If I for example jump up in the air and hit a ceiling above me, is it still called? What exactly are the differences? Here is what the Unity documentation says and the code I was using.

"OnCollisionEnter is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun touching another rigidbody/collider."

"OnCollisionStay is called once per frame for every collider/rigidbody that is touching rigidbody/collider."

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && OnGround == True)
{
    rigidbody.velocity.y = jumpHeight;
}

onGround = false;

function OnCollisionStay()
{
    onGround = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is really pretty simple. Let's assume that the collision starts, the colliders keep intersecting for a period of time (several frames), and after a while they separate again. The events then are:

- OnCollisionEnter for the first frame only, and never again until after an OnCollisionExit
- OnCollisionStay for the entire duration (all frames)
- OnCollisionExit for the last frame only

> Even if its called once per frame, If I for example jump up in the air and hit a ceiling above me, is it still called?

Sure it is. But then for that new collision. If there is a period in between where you're not colliding with anything however, you will not get OnCollisionStay events for that duration.

To get a deeper understanding of these events, it's perhaps best to create a simple demo scene in which you manually intersect two colliders, and have some text written to the console for the various events.

Comment: but when I come into contact with the wall above, and try and push the button again while its in contact, it still does nothing. Does that mean that it was called but started "sleeping"?

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing your exact setup.

Comment: I did test this out a little with sound. I noticed how the ball would jump off the platform, hit the platform above it and make a sound, but when it landed it did not make a sound. But as far as "sleeping" goes im still pretty new to the concept.

Comment: If it would be at all possible to make a tiny example project which demonstrates this behaviour, then perhaps do so. If I have the time, I could have a look at that. But there are plenty of reasons why something might or might not work. And without seeing what exactly you've done and what your settings are, it's hard to guess.

Comment: Sure How would I send it to you?

Comment: Make it available online somewhere. Dropbox, Github, whatever

Comment: let me know if you have trouble getting it, I just started using dropbox a few days ago

Comment: Okay, change the beginning of your OnCollisionStay function in BallBehavior.js to `function OnCollisionStay (col : Collision){ Debug.Log("Stay: " + col.collider.gameObject.name);` You will see it prints when it hits the Platform as well as Platform2 and Platform3. So the problem is not in collisions going undetected or not getting signalled. It's in the rest of your logic.

Comment: More than likely you want your audio triggering to be done in OnCollisionEnter. I.e. just once and upon first contact. I'd say that's the easiest route.

Comment: yea true probably just over thinking it. I changed the input from GetKeyDown to just GetKey and it ended up sticking to the ceiling. But it does make more sense than it used to. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Bart's answer is correct so this answer is more of an example of how you would use the two.

So `OnCollisionEnter` will fire 1 per collision case lets say for example a ball hitting a wall and `OnCollisionEnter` could maybe do some damage to the wall or destroy the wall. (Like breakout)

```
//Ball
#pragma strict

function OnCollisionEnter (col : Collision)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "Wall")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

However in `OnCollisionStay` you would use that if you have a character with hit points that steps into a poison cloud and removes continuous hit points or removes incremental timed hit points as long as `OnCollisionStay` continues to fire after a given amount of time. (I'm thinking castlevania SOTH)

```
//PoisonGasCloud
#pragma strict
function OnCollisionStay(collisionInfo : Collision)
{

    collisionTime = Time.deltaTime;

    if ( collisionTime > 5)
    {
        hero.hp-=10;
    }
}
```

Note:I usually code in C# so my UnityScript might be a little off.

Comment: yea I understand, OnCollision Enter is called once, and OnCollisionStay is called as long as it is still being called.

Answer (score 2):

- When collision start: OnCollisionEnter & OnCollisionStay
- When collision continue: OnCollisionStay
- When collision end: OnCollisionExit

Note 1: OnCollisionStay & OnCollisionExit will not be called simultaneously.

Note 2:OnCollisionEnter call before OnCollisionStay.